# Sort list of objects by list of integers

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a list of integers (it's called L1): {14,16,12}

and I have a list of objects (L2):

```
{
    [name: 'a1', id: 5], 
    [name: 'a2', id: 16],
    [name: 'a2', id: 8],
    [name: 'a2', id: 14]
}
```

I want to order L2 according to the order of L1.

I tried:

```
L2.OrderBy(Function(o) L1.IndexOf(o.id)).ToArray()
```

But I got:

```
{
    [name: 'a1', id: 5],
    [name: 'a2', id: 8],
    [name: 'a2', id: 14],       
    [name: 'a2', id: 16]
}
```

It happens because 5 and 8 are not found in L1, that's why `indexOf` returns -1.

How Can I sort it by the list and preserve the other items in L2 that are not found in L1 in the same order?

**Update:**
The output should be:
14,
16,
5,
8

The steps:

```
step 1)

L1 -> first number is 14.
put 14 in the top:

14, 5, 16, 8. 

step 2)

L1 -> second number is 16.
put 16 in the top (after 14):

14, 16, 5, 8. 

step 3)
L1 -> third number is 12.
12 is not found in L2.

So the output is: 14, 16, 5, 8.
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Preserving the order is one thing, but where should these items (5,8) be placed? At the start of the sorted list? At the end? In the middle? Spread evenly throughout?

Comment: What is the expected output in the case you provided?

Comment: So the desired output for `id` is `5, 14, 8, 16`?

Comment: The result of `IndexOf` for the missing objects is `-1` which comes *before* all other items. If you want the missing items to appear after the others, change your lambda to return a large value (eg int.MaxValue) if `IndexOf` returns -1. If not, please explain what the expected result is

Comment: I updated my question with output and explanation.. Sorry and thank you all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you want to preserve ordering if all others are changing their place. However, maybe you mean following that uses the old index as fallback value:

```
Dim ordered = L2.
    Select(Function(obj, index) New With {.Obj = obj, .OldIndex = index, .IndexInL1 = L1.IndexOf(obj.id)}).
    OrderBy(Function(x) If(x.IndexInL1 >= 0, x.IndexInL1, Int32.MaxValue)).
    ThenBy(Function(x) x.OldIndex).
    Select(Function(x) x.Obj).
    ToArray()
```

So this results in a stable order where all objects which id is not in the id-list keep their place compared to other objects which id is not in that list.

Comment: I will do it after I will understand and check it.. thank you very much!